# How to avoid the refresh effect of the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Refresh effect to the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter while typing in the text field that loads data in an Autocomplete manner. I used to call the the following function `firebaseUserSearch` withe help of  `onTextChanged` method to fill the adapter. At each time when the `firebaseUserSearch` is being called it refreshes the recylerview which i don't want , if the result is already present there.

```
private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder>(
            Users.class,
            R.layout.list_layout,
            SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(SearchActivity.UsersViewHolder viewHolder, final Users model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getPlace(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.relLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("place", model.getPlace());
                    intent.putExtra("image", model.getImage());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    };
    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

`onTextChanged` will fire evey time you type something in the textfield.

You might want to use `afterTextChanged`.

Here is an example -

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(
    new TextWatcher() {
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        private Timer timer=new Timer();
        private final long DELAY = 500; // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO: do what you need here (refresh list)
                        // you will probably need to use runOnUiThread(Runnable action) for some specific actions
                    }
                }, 
                DELAY
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change the search term you create a new query and a new adapter, which leads to a complete reload (and repaint) of the data. The standard `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` has no way to prevent this.

If you want a more intelligent adapter, you will have to create it yourself. You'll have to compare each item you get back from the query with items you already have, and only pass the actual changes along to your adapter.

While that is definitely possible, it is quite some work. If you get stuck along the way, feel free to post a question that [reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).